# Outlook.com does not allow stylesheet to be loaded externally?

Tags: css, outlook

It looks like Outlook.com prevents a stylesheet to be loaded from an external url this way:

http://cdn.xxxx.com/email/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

When I download the email via POP3, everything is just fine. However, when I open the same email in outlook.com somehow the css is blocked. I am suprised that it does not block the images inside the email and prefers to block only the css. How come?? Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice , use inline style on all elements.

It's not just outlook, gmail has similar issues ( security reasons )

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice when making a mailer always use inline style.

All Outlook versions and others like gmail, yahoo, hotmail have a good support for inline style.

Comment: It seems that inline styling is also somehow prevented by Outlook.com.

Comment: are you talking about `padding` property? if yes, then yes outlook and hotmail doesn't support padding feature.

Comment: Not just padding. Some other elements too. This is very weird, because they seem to remove inline elements like "float" too.

Comment: I would suggest you better use the table. don't reply too much on CSS,